# unmet dependencies while installing cinnamon

Tags: cinnamon

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
ashley@ashley-SVE15113FDW:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get install cinnamon
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
cinnamon : Depends: cinnamon-common (= 2.0.14-20131203040047-quantal) but 2.0.14-20131203040103-precise is to be installed
        Recommends: cinnamon-screensaver but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: gir1.2-cjsdbus-1.0 but it is not installable
        Recommends: cinnamon-bluetooth but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ashley@ashley-SVE15113FDW:/etc/apt$
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove the ppa:merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa from the list . You can do that by going

Software and Updates -> Other software.

Now add this new ppa by typing :

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-nightly`

Now you can install it using

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cinnamon`